# Challenge C programming

Tags: c

What should I do so that the program run without any mistakes ..

```
#include <stdio.h>


    int i= 0;
    while (i< SIZE){
        j= i+1;
        while (j<SIZE){
            if (myList[i]+ myList [j] == target){
                printf("%d AND %d\n", i, j);

            }
            j= j+1;
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
```

In order to compile and execute this code, you must type this into an editor. Make sure that all required variables are suitably declared. Also make sure that the values are input using `scanf()` prior to executing these if-else statements. If you run the compiler several times, it will help you to identify the variables that must be declared.

Question: Write a C program that will read in N=1000 integers, i1, i2, …, iN.   These numbers are not sorted and you may assume that these integers also do not have any regular pattern. After reading these N integers, your program must now read in a new integer called the Target. Find all pairs of integers ij and ik from these N integers such that ij + ik   = Target.

Comment: What this program is supposed to do?What problem you are facing?

Comment: I think it will be best if you edit your code and include the variable declarations and also explain what your program does ( or what you are expecting to do ). If we do it without knowing what you are trying to do, who knows what we will come up with.

Comment: can `j` be equal to `k` ??

Comment: are you (_aren't you_) missing a `main()` somewhere?

Comment: seems like an assignment question to me

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried your code, and have got it to work. I am assuming that `j` can be equal to `k`. If they cannot be equal, then I have indicated which part is to be changed in the code ( There its `i` and `j` instead of `j` and `k` ). Well here's the fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10   // You can change SIZE here
int main()
 {
    int myList[SIZE],target;     
    printf("Enter 10 Numbers\n");   
    for(int k=0;k<SIZE;k++)
      {
       scanf("%d",&myList[k]);
      }
    printf("Enter the target\n");  
    scanf("%d",&target);   
    int i= 0,j;
    while (i< SIZE)
      {
        j=i;        // if i and j should not be equal just change it to j=i+1
        while (j<SIZE)
          {
            if (myList[i]+ myList [j] == target)
              {
                printf("%d AND %d\n", i, j);
              }
            j= j+1;
        }
        i=i+1;
      }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I have taken `SIZE=10` for convenience because I don't want to enter 1000 numbers. You can just change `SIZE` to 1000 whenever you want.

Cheers.......Hope this is what you wanted.